# 'this' key word inside arrow functions

Tags: javascript

trying to learn the 'this' key word inside an arrow function properly.

after reading and watching some videos i understood that with the regular function the 'this' key word will be defined whenever the function is invoked.

and 'this' inside the arrow function will be defined according to the value of 'this' wherever you build that function.

so i opened the console and played with two objects and the two functions.

i did this:

```
const reg = {
    reg1: "reg1",
    reg2: {
            reg3: 'reg3',
            regFunc: function(){console.log(this)}
    }
}

const arrow = {
    arrow1: "arrow1",
    arrow2: {
            arrow3: 'arrow3',
            arrowFunc: () => {console.log(this)}
    }
}

reg.reg2.regFunc()
VM712:5 {reg3: "reg3", regFunc: ƒ}

arrow.arrow2.arrowFunc()
VM712:13 Window {parent: Window, opener: null, top: Window, length: 1, frames: Window, …}
```

for the reg Object i get it because it was invoked inside the reg2 object which it shows me.

but for the arrow Object the this keyword in the arrow function was created inside the arrow2 object inside arrow.

so why isn't the value of it in the arrow object arrow2? why is it the global window?

Comment: Because arrow functions adopt the `this` of their surrounding (function) scope. Since this arrow function isn't inside any other function, its enclosing scope is global, thus its `this` is the global object.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is defined for a `function` execution context.

In the code that defines `const arrow` there is no `function` context, only the arrow function. So the lexical `this` is the global object (in sloppy mode) or `undefined` in strict mode.

It is a common misunderstanding that an object literal (the one assigned to `arrow` or to `arrow2`) would somehow bind `this` to it.

Answer (score 1):

In arrow functions `this` is treated similarly to a normal variable (a `const`ant one). An arrow function records the value of `this` at the moment of creation and `this` will always point to that value inside the arrow function (since you can't reassign `this`).

Answer (score 0):

Because arrow functions do not bind their own this but instead inherit from the parent scope which in this case is the global object

Comment: I know you would not be able to comment at the moment, but if you are answering, do ensure it's meaningful.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` pointer points `window` object as it is parent. And `this` in arrow functions always points to the parent scope, here it is `window` object.

If you wrap that arrow function with class or function(for instance), then `this` will point that object.

```
const func = {
    b: {
        d: function() {
            console.log(this)
        }
    }
}

const arrow = {
    b: {
        d: function() {
            const e = () => {
                console.log(this)
            }
            return e()
        }
    }
}

func.b.d()  >> {d:f}
arrow.b.d() >> {d:f}
```